# AjaxPro equivalent to DataContract renaming such as [DataMember(Name = "FooBar")]

Tags: c#, ajax, json, datacontract, ajaxpro

I use [AjaxPro](http://www.ajaxpro.info/) to write do requests like:

```
[AjaxMethod]
public MyClass GetMyClass()
{
   return new MyClass();
}
```

Where MyClass holds fields like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [AjaxNonSerializable]
    public string DoNotSerialzeMe;

    [AjaxProperty]
    public string WantsToBeSerialized;
}
```

So far, so good. But I cannot find any equivalent to renaming fields by `[DataMember(Name = "FooBar")]`. I use the same classes with REST requests and need to rebuild their DataContract in AjaxPro.

Comment: Are you sure AjaxPro does support data contracts API? I'm unable to find any indication of it anywhere, including the project source code.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Meanwhile I found some equivalents to DataContract attributes that work in AjaxPro but I still need some help. I updated the question.